# Google Enterprise Recaptcha scored base metrics not recording the request

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I followed the **Frontend integration javascript** example and it is clearly working.

I was able to assess the token in my django backend which I received from `grecaptcha.enterprise.execute` with an action `login`.

But when I look at the metrics of that site key the request or any analysis is not captured.

**EDITED:**
Below is my NuxtJS implementation

```
methods: {
  login() {
    const _this = this;
    try {
      grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.enterprise
          .execute(process.env.SITE_KEY, {
            action: "login"
          })
          .then(function(token) {
            _this.auth.token = token;
            try {
              _this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
                data: _this.auth
              });
            } catch (e) {
              _this.$notify({
                group: "login",
                type: "error",
                title: "ERROR:",
                text: e.response.data.error
              });
            }
          });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      this.$notify({
        group: "login",
        type: "error",
        title: "ERROR:",
        text: "Captcha Error"
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly have you tried and what do you want to achieve ? Please include as much details as possible that may be important.

Comment: I edited my question by adding a code snippet. I want my captured data to show when I check the metrics of score based site key